# Django: Combining querysets with different filters

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model `Book` with a foreign key to model `Publisher`.

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
   ...

class Book(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    ...
```

In a separate application I have a model `Task` which can have a generic foreign key to any other model.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_pk = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_pk') 
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

I want to be able to add a method to the `Publisher` model which returns all tasks that are associated with it or any of the publisher's books. I can do them separately:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_tasks(self):
        return Task.objects.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self), object_pk=self.pk)

    def get_book_tasks(self):
        return Task.objects.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Book), object_pk__in=self.related_books.values_list('pk', flat=True))
```

But I want to be able to combine both of those into a method that returns a single queryset, allowing me to further filter it by the task properties (like a `get_all_tasks()` method that would allow me to do `Publisher.objects.first().get_all_tasks().filter(complete=False)`.)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using [complex lookups with `Q` objects.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

> A `Q object (django.db.models.Q)` is an object used to encapsulate a collection of keyword arguments.

These can be created similar to the `filter`method on querysets, but then combined using set logic.

For your example, create one `Q` for the publisher tasks, and another for the book tasks and combine (`|`) them, like so:

```
from django.db.models import Q
class Publisher(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_all_tasks(self):
        publisher_tasks = Q(
            content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self),
            object_pk=self.pk)
        book_tasks = Q(
             content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Book),
             object_pk__in=self.related_books.values_list('pk', flat=True))
        return Task.objects.filter(publisher_tasks  | book_tasks)
```

You can even limit code duplication by pulling the `Q` sections out, like so:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    ...

    def publisher_task_query(self):
        return Q(
            content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self),
            object_pk=self.pk)

    def book_task_query(self):
        return Q(
             content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Book),
             object_pk__in=self.related_books.values_list('pk', flat=True))

    def get_tasks(self):
        return Task.objects.filter(self.publisher_task_query())

    def get_book_tasks(self):
        return Task.objects.filter(self.book_task_query())

    def get_all_tasks(self):
        return Task.objects.filter(self.publisher_task_query() | self.book_task_query())
```